# efficiently extract rows from a pandas DataFrame ignoring missing index labels

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am looking for a more efficient equivalent of

```
df.reindex(labels).dropna(subset=[0])
```

that avoids including the NaN rows for missing label in the result rather than having to delete them after `reindex` puts them in.

Equivalently I am loooking for an efficient version of

```
df.loc[labels]
```

that silently ignores labels that are not in `df.index`, ie the result may have fewer rows than elements of `labels`.

I need something that is efficient when the numbers of rows, columns and labels are all large and there is a significant miss rate. Specifically, I'm looking for something sublinear in the length of the dataset.

---

#### Update 1

Here is a concrete demonstration of the issue following on from @MaxU's answer:

```
In [2]: L = 10**7
   ...: M = 10**4
   ...: N = 10**9
   ...: np.random.seed([3, 1415])
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(L, 2))
   ...: labels = np.random.randint(N, size=M)
   ...: M-len(set(labels)) 
   ...: 
   ...: 
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: %timeit df[df.index.isin(set(labels))]
904 ms ± 59.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit df.loc[df.index.intersection(set(labels))]
207 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [5]: %timeit df.loc[np.intersect1d(df.index, labels)]
427 ms ± 37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [6]: %timeit df.loc[labels[labels<L]]
329 µs ± 23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit df.iloc[labels[labels<L]]
161 µs ± 8.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The last 2 examples are ~1000 times faster than those iterating over `df.index`. This demonstrates that `df.loc[labels]` does not iterate over the index and that dataframes have an efficient index structure, ie `df.index` does indeed index.

So the question is how do I get something as efficient as `df.loc[labels[labels<L]]` when `df.index` is not a contiguous sequence of numbers. A partial solution is the the original

```
In [8]: %timeit df.reindex(labels).dropna(subset=[0])
1.81 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That is still a ~100 times faster than the suggested solutions, but still losing an order of magnitude to what may be possible.

---

#### Update 2

To further demonstrate that it is possible to get sublinear performance even without assuptions on the index repeat the above with a string index

```
In [16]: df.index=df.index.map(str)
    ...: labels = np.array(list(map(str, labels)))
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [17]: %timeit df[df.index.isin(set(labels))]
657 ms ± 48.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [18]: %timeit df.loc[df.index.intersection(set(labels))]
974 ms ± 160 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [19]: %timeit df.reindex(labels).dropna()
8.7 ms ± 121 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

***So to be clear I am after something that is more efficient than `df.reindex(labels).dropna()`. This is already sublinear in `df.shape[0]` and makes no assumptions about the index, therefore so should the solution.***

The issue I want to address is that `df.reindex(labels)` will include `NaN` rows for missing labels that then need removing with `dropna`. I am after an equivalent of `df.reindex(labels)` that does not put them there in the first place, without scanning the entire `df.index` to figure out the missing labels. This must be possible at least in principle: If `reindex` can efficiently handle missing labels on the fly by inserting dummy rows, it should be possible to handle them even more efficiently on the fly by doing nothing.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect your attempt to find a sublinear solution in the length of the dataset. This is impossible - pandas does not index the dataset in a BST. At the very least you would need to sort the index, which is polylogarithmic.

Comment: @AmiTavory I have ammended the question to demonstrate that what I am after is possible in principle. When the `df.index` are just consecutive numbers then `df.loc[labels[labels<df.shape[0]]]` is can be several orders of magnitude faster than `df[df.index.isin(setlabels)]`. Unfortunately my index is not a sequence of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Daniel Mahler, had you specified in your question that there are further assumptions on the index (e.g., that it is consecutive numbers), my answer would have been different. I don't think this bears much on the original question, and I recommend that you follow MaxU's example and time it to your specific case. If your index is unsorted strings, e.g., you will get very different results probably.

Comment: @AmiTavory `df.reindex(labels).dropna()` is already sublinear and makes no assumptions about the index. I have updated the question showing this using a string index.

Comment: Daniel Mahler that is indeed interesting. Thanks for showing this!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a small comparison for different approaches.

Sample DF (shape: 10.000.000 x 2):

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**7, 2))
labels = np.random.randint(10**9, size=10**4)

In [88]: df.shape
Out[88]: (10000000, 2)
```

valid (existing labels):

```
In [89]: (labels <= 10**7).sum()
Out[89]: 1008
```

invalid (not existing labels):

```
In [90]: (labels > 10**7).sum()
Out[90]: 98992
```

**Timings:**

```
In [103]: %timeit df[df.index.isin(set(labels))]
943 ms ± 7.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [104]: %timeit df.loc[df.index.intersection(set(labels))]
360 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [105]: %timeit df.loc[np.intersect1d(df.index, labels)]
513 ms ± 655 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps make things concrete. Try `%timeit df.loc[labels[labels<L]]`. That illustrates the issue I am getting at `.loc[labesl]` does not scan the dataframe index.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I applaud your empirically testing things.